# Diagnostics:Application killed by user

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Any idea why my application gets killed? I am the only user of this nodes.
Also my history server doesn't show anything. How I trace this down further and realize who killed it and why and how to fix it?[image]

```
ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:/home/hadoop/yarnpp/workloads$ yarn application -status application_1448835095947_0003
15/12/05 17:34:44 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.0.1.190:8032
15/12/05 17:34:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/05 17:34:45 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at /10.0.1.190:10200
Application Report : 
    Application-Id : application_1448835095947_0003
    Application-Name : GRIDMIX_GENERATE_INPUT_DATA
    Application-Type : TEZ
    User : ubuntu
    Queue : default
    Start-Time : 1449262591969
    Finish-Time : 1449263455112
    Progress : 100%
    State : KILLED
    Final-State : KILLED
    Tracking-URL : http://anmol-vm1-new:8088/cluster/app/application_1448835095947_0003
    RPC Port : -1
    AM Host : N/A
    Diagnostics : Application killed by user.
```

Comment: This indicates, a user killed the application by calling "yarn application -kill <application id>".

Comment: hey I didn't kill it nor there is another user assigned to this

Comment: That's strange. I am not familiar with Tez jobs. But, I have observed that, usually this error comes, only when the application is explicitly killed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get more information from the yarn logs using the yarn cli:

yarn logs -applicationId your_application_id

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.0/yarn-monitoring-clusters-applications/topics/yarn-use-cli-view-logs-applications.html